# How do you utilize azure policy to deny RBAC permissions?

Tags: azure, azure-policy

Sample code below. I need to format an azure policy to block write permission actions to a storage account. Because this permission exists on several role definitions, the permission action itself needs to be blocked. Is this possible with azure policy?

```
    "policyRule": {
      "if": {
        "allOf": [
          {
            "field": "Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/permissions.actions[*]",
            "equals": "Microsoft.Storage/storageaccounts/write"
          }
        ]
      },
      "then": {
        "effect": "Deny"
      }
    }
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

**Yes, you can utilize azure policy to deny RBAC permissions.**

To do the same try using the below azure policy by **timwarner-msft** in this [**GitHub**](https://github.com/Azure/azure-policy/blob/master/samples/Authorization/allowed-role-definitions/azurepolicy.json) blog:

```json
{
"name": "deny-role-definitions",
"properties": {
"displayName": "Denied Role Definitions",
"description": "This policy defines an denied list of role definitions",
"mode": "All",
"parameters": {
"roleDefinitionIds": {
"type": "array",
"metadata": {
"description": "The list of role definition Ids",
"displayName": "Denied Role Definitions"
}
}
},
"policyRule": {
"allOf": [
{
"field": "type",
"equals": "Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments"
},
"effect": "deny"
}
}
}
}
```

Comment: this denies a role assignment onto a scope, it doesn't block the permission to specifically deny write access to a storage account.